# How do I force a header on an octet-stream returned by a PHP document?

Tags: php, header, content-type

I already tried to find an answer to this question on this site but I'm a bit unexperienced and my knowledge is limited yet.

My situation is as follows: I have an external PHP file (say http://example.org/get.php) (which I cannot edit) that returns an MP3 file as an octet-stream. The problem is that I need it to be an audio/mp3 in order to use it with an HTML5 audio player. How can I achieve this?

I think I cannot just do something like

```
$mp3_url = 'http://example.org/get.php?file=123'; header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
```

, can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to setup a proxy on your server, e.g. `/your/script.php` might look like

```php
header('Content-Type: audio/mp3', true, 200);
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
```

*(security checks skipped)*

Then you can use it as `<a href="/your/script.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fget.php%3Ffile%3D123">link</a>`

Another way is to setup a proxy using Web server such as Nginx or Apache.

Comment: Is there a way to include that in an already existing PHP script or does it have to be in its own PHP file? Other than that, many thanks!

Comment: @AidanLumina, you should create new script somewhere in the public directory of your Web server such as `/www/xproject/public/proxy.php`, then make requests to it from client: `http://yourdomain.com/proxy.php?url=...`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that makes sense. The actual mp3 file is not stored on the server but forwarded to the client, just with a different header. Is that correct? If it's not, can you please try to elaborate how the situation is? That would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AidanLumina, instead of requesting `http://remote.com/a.mp3` you'll request `http://your-own.com/proxy.php?url=...remote-url-encoded-here`. So if you have an HTML with links to the remote mp3, you'll have to change them appropriately.

Comment: I know about that. I'm pretty sure I'd make my server easily vulnerable if I'd do that. I expect that many people will use what I'm trying to achieve frequently, so if I'd use a proxy.php, the bandwidth usage would go up like a rocket. Is there any alternative? JS? An external service which does this? Maybe a workaround?

Comment: @AidanLumina, of course there should be some kind of security check. In simplest case the server generates a hash(md5, sha1 etc.) based  on private key: `md5($key . $url)` and passes it to the view: `<a href="/proxy.php?url=...&hash={$hash}..."...`; then proxy.php generates the new hash based on the same private key and `$_GET['url']`. If hashes don't match, then nothing happens. And this is the simplest case. More advanced way would be through a Web server proxy. I'd recommend Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Use another php script to act as a proxy, i.e:

```
<?php

$mp3 = file_get_contents("http://example.org/get.php?file=123");
header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
echo $mp3;
```

Answer (score -1):

use `audio/mpeg` as content-type

Comment: audio/mp3 is valid from what I know and have seen. Google seems to confirm that.